# How to refactor an async function with Promise inside of it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise, refactoring

Having this async function that returns a Promise:

```
async function doSomething(userId) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const query = 'my-query';

    const roomAggregate = Room.aggregate(query).allowDiskUse(true);
    Room.aggregatePaginate(roomAggregate, async function (err, data) {
      if (err || !data) {
        throw err;
        return {
          success: false,
          rooms: [],
        };
      } else {
        const rooms = [];
        for (let room of data.docs) {
          const roomId = room._id;
          room = await computeAThing(room, {
            loadWriteUps: false,
            loadCreators: false,
          });
          room.userCompleted = await computeBThing(userId, roomId);
          rooms.push(room);
        }
        return resolve({
          rooms,
          success: true,
          paginator: {
            // some data related to pagination
          },
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I'm not sure if it really needs to contain `new Promise` inside as it is already declared as `async function`. Is it mandatory in this case?

Because when that part was removed and at the end instead of `return resolve({...})` it is only `return {...}` it seems to not settle.

Here is the modified code with `new Promise` and different return:

```
async function doSomething(userId) {
  const query = 'my-query';

  const roomAggregate = Room.aggregate(query).allowDiskUse(true);
  Room.aggregatePaginate(roomAggregate, async function (err, data) {
    if (err || !data) {
      throw err;
      return {
        success: false,
        rooms: [],
      };
    } else {
      const rooms = [];
      for (let room of data.docs) {
        const roomId = room._id;
        room = await computeAThing(room, {
          loadWriteUps: false,
          loadCreators: false,
        });
        room.userCompleted = await computeBThing(userId, roomId);
        rooms.push(room);
      }
      return {
        rooms,
        success: true,
        paginator: {
          // some data related to pagination
        },
      };
    }
  });
}
```

This method is used somewhere else in this way:

```
 const myInfo = await someObj.doSomething('myUserId');
```

and then checked:

```
if (myInfo.success) { ... }
```

For the first way of writing the function it works fine, for the second one `myInfo` is `undefined` and it throws and error that cannot read `success` of undefined.

Is something missing from the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second version I can see that you actually not returning anything from `doSomething` so I think you should do the below:

```
  async function doSomething(userId) {
  const query = 'my-query';

  const roomAggregate = Room.aggregate(query).allowDiskUse(true);
  const obj = Room.aggregatePaginate(roomAggregate, async function (err, data) {
    if (err || !data) {
      throw err;
      return {
        success: false,
        rooms: [],
      };
    } else {
      const rooms = [];
      for (let room of data.docs) {
        const roomId = room._id;
        room = await computeAThing(room, {
          loadWriteUps: false,
          loadCreators: false,
        });
        room.userCompleted = await computeBThing(userId, roomId);
        rooms.push(room);
      }
      return {
        rooms,
        success: true,
        paginator: {
          // some data related to pagination
        },
      };
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
```

In general, you don't need to explicitly return a Promise in an async function as by default the returned value will be wrapped in a Promise , whatever it is. You just need to return something

Comment: there's other mistakes and anti-patterns left in the code here. see my post for details.

Answer (score 0):

`Room.aggregatePaginat` is written in coninuation-passing style, which does not interface well with promises. A generic `promisify` function can be used to convert any continuation-passing style function into a promise-based one. If you don't wish to write this function yourself, it is provided by Node as `util.promisify` -

```js
const promisify = f => (...args) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    f(...args, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data))
  )
```

Now it's easy to refactor your `doSomething`. Note use of `Promise.all` means all `rooms` data is processed in parallel rather than in series -

```
async function doSomething(userId) {
  const query = 'my-query'
  const roomAggregate = Room.aggregate(query).allowDiskUse(true)
  const {docs:rooms} = await promisify(Room.aggregatePaginate)(roomAggregate)
  return {
    rooms:
      await Promise.all(rooms.map(async room => ({
        ...await computeAThing(room, {loadWriteUps: false, loadCreators: false}),
        userCompleted: await computeBThing(userId, room._id)
      }))),
    success: true,
    paginator: ...
  }
}
```

Also you should avoid things like `{ success: true }` because a resolved promise is inherently "successful". A rejected one is not.

And watch out for `return` occurring after a `throw`. In this case the `return` is unreachable so it doesn't do what you think it's doing.

```js
if (err || !data) {
  throw err;
  return {            // unreachable 
    success: false,   // these four lines
    rooms: [],        // are completely ignored
  };                  // by javascript runtime
}
```

Again, `{ success: false }` goes against the Promise pattern anyway. If you want to recover from a rejection and recover with an empty list of `{ rooms: [] }`, do it like this instead -

```js
doSomething(user.id)
  .catch(err => ({ rooms: [] }))
  .then(res => console.log(res.rooms))
```

Better yet, you can `try..catch` inside `doSomething` and return the appropriate empty response in the event of an error. This prevents the error from bubbling up and forcing the user to handle it -

```js
async function doSomething(userId) {
  try {                           // try
    const query = 'my-query'
    const roomAggregate = Room.aggregate(query).allowDiskUse(true)
    const {docs:rooms} = await promisify(Room.aggregatePaginate)(roomAggregate)
    return {
      rooms:
        await Promise.all(rooms.map(async room => ({
          ...await computeAThing(room, {loadWriteUps: false, loadCreators: false}),
          userCompleted: await computeBThing(userId, room._id)
        }))),
      paginator: ...
    }
  }
  catch (err) {             // catch
    return { rooms: [] }
  }
}
```

```js
doSomething(user.id)
  .then(res => console.log(res.rooms))
```